# Merging questions about deduplication of files and folders?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Can the following questions be merged? These questions all look a lot similar and they all have valuable answers (most of which are similar, which is 'use fdupes'). Are we going to maintain a different question for

1. [finding duplicate images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214355/is-there-a-way-to-find-duplicate-images-in-ubuntu)
2. [finding duplicate music files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3865/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files)
3. [finding duplicate files and folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59107/find-duplicate-files-and-folders-and-move-these-to-a-different-folder)

The third question is marked as a duplicate of the second, but the best answer is found in the third question (this is subjective I know). My personal favorite is [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/59113/115155) because it explains the basic options and has valuable notes (which might be edited into the answer).

Answer (score 2):

The [first question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214355/is-there-a-way-to-find-duplicate-images-in-ubuntu) is specifically about pictures, so I think it should be kept separate.

The [second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3865/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files) and [third](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59107/find-duplicate-files-and-folders-and-move-these-to-a-different-folder) could be merged, though. That seems like a good idea. Strictly speaking the topics are a bit different--one is about deleting duplicates and the other is about moving them. But in effect they are presenting the same kind of information.